# Git Integration Manager Workflow -- one or multiple repositories?

Tags: git, workflow, integration

I've read about the [Integration Manager Workflow](http://progit.org/book/ch5-1.html), and it looks very suitable for our development process (one lead developer for the project, who reviews the work of fellow developers before it's committed to the project's repository).

However, one thing is unclear to me. In this visualization from the Pro Git book it appears as though each developer has his own (remote) repository to push to:

[image]

In [this chapter](http://progit.org/book/ch5-2.html) (section "Private Small Team"), though, they seem to be using branches to achieve the same kind of workflow.

Is this correct? Which tactic should we use; branches or multiple repositories? I'm guessing it's harder to maintain a timeline of commits if you pull work in from a different repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the workflow you linked to but it adds a little more overhead. Biggest advantage is that you can work asynchronously and only need access to the server.

You don't have to use public and private repos though. You can still have a pull based workflow if you have access to the other devs repositories, where the devs commit to their local repos and you pull from them.

So for example. Say dev A is working on branch featureA. He commits to his local branch featureA and lets you know "feature A is ready now, you can pull from me". Here you could setup his repository as a remote like "git remote add devA /path/to/devA/repo.git" and just git pull devA featureA (or fetch first, check the code and then merge).

[image]

This of course assumes that you have access to their repositories via e.g. the network, ssh or http.

Comment: But is it also possible to have one central repository, with the non-maintainer developers only pushing to additional branches, which the maintainer then merges into the master?

Comment: Ah, your example is very clear, thanks. Does this workflow have any disadvantages compared to doing all this in one repository (e.g. lost commit history etc)?

Comment: The thing is with git, you never have just one repository :) The developers will always have a repo of their own. It's just a matter of how you want the repository DAG to look like, i.e. who pushes what to what repo, or who pulls what from which repo etc. Makes any sense?

Comment: So would I be pulling from their local repositories (i.e. the work they've `commit`ed but not `push`ed)?

Comment: And yes, it's possible to have one central repo where people push their branches too. Trade off here is that they have to push up their whole branches so the central repo will contain all developers branches and it can easily get messy when there are 100 branches there :) But it's definitly an option. Should they push all their branches or should you pull from them? It's a matter of taste really and how you would like to work together.

Comment: Exactly. They just commit to their repos and you pull from them. Another advantage with them pushing to a central repo is that you can take backups of that repo and the code from all devs will be backed up, assuming they have pushed their code that is.

Comment: You pulling from them obviously give you absolute control of what is brought in to the main repo and they can have read-only access to the main repo and pull in e.g. master to get updates from the rest of the devs features and fixes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8781/discussion-between-rijk-and-magnus-skog)

Answer (score 1):

This question has been around for a while but the approach given in the question is a valid one. It's called the [Forking Workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/forking-workflow). Well, it's very similar to the one above and seems to match it in intent and purpose but at least there's a nice writeup that should clarify the strategy.